# Call to undefined method mysqli_stmt::bindValue

Tags: php, mysqli

I have the following function

```
<?php 

  error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set("display_errors", true);
  @ $dbh= new mysqli('localhost', 'root', 'hsenidsoft', '1005');
  $stmt = $dbh->prepare("CALL populateDefaultTrainStructureTest(?,?)");
  $startdate = '2011-05-16';
  $counter =1 ;
  $stmt->bindValue(1, $startdate, PDO::PARAM_DATE);

  $stmt->bindValue(2, $counter, PDO::PARAM_INT);
  $stmt->execute();
?>
```

when I execute the function I got:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined method mysqli_stmt::bindValue() in /var/www/sp.php on line 8 error

Comment: What's the `var_dump($stmt)` before the call? Also: why prepare a call to a stored procedure? It's prepared already. :-)

Comment: its saying


object(mysqli_stmt)#2 (9) { ["affected_rows"]=> int(0) ["insert_id"]=> int(0) ["num_rows"]=> int(0) ["param_count"]=> int(2) ["field_count"]=> int(0) ["errno"]=> int(0) ["error"]=> string(0) "" ["sqlstate"]=> string(5) "00000" ["id"]=> int(1) } Fatal error: Call to undefined method mysqli_stmt::bindValue() in /var/www/sp.php on line 11

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no `bindValue` function but there is [mysqli_stmt::bind_param](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php)

Comment: Indeed, [`bindValue()` belongs to PDO](http://us2.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindvalue.php).